# Linear maps and matrix representations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a question. I know that every linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ can be expressed as $T(x)=Ax$. Where A is a matrix. Does this hold for any basis or just the standard basis? I would really appreciate if someone tells me if it does or doesn't for a general basis and if it doesn't hold for nonstandard basis then what extra conditions are required for it to be represented in the form written above?

Comment: [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) may be of interest to you. The answer to your question is presented there.

Answer (score 0):

No, any basis will do.

[These](https://youtu.be/kYB8IZa5AuE) [videos](https://youtu.be/XkY2DOUCWMU) by Grant Sanderson may help you develop an intuition for why our choice in basis does not matter when describing a linear transformation.

To summarize, each element $v_i$ of a vector $\mathbf v$ in $\mathbb R^n$ essential describes "how many" of the $i$th basis vector to add up when constructing the vector $\mathbf v$. In $\mathbb R^3$,

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} = ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3
$$

where $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is any basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

Each column of a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ describes where the basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$  "land" when moved through the transformation described by the matrix $A$. The scheme that we use to describe basis vectors does not matter, only how they move with respect to the way we describe them. This final idea in discussed in [this](https://youtu.be/P2LTAUO1TdA) additional video by Sanderson, and is key to many application of linear algebra.

Comment: Another way to look at this: take any transformation $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. Now tilt you head by $45 ^\circ$ and then draw a new "$x$ and $y$-axis" from this perspective. Pick two new unit basis vectors along these axes that we'll call $\langle 1,0 \rangle$ and $\langle 0,1 \rangle$. Now describe your transformation using this new basis. You'll end up with a different matrix that describes the exact same transformation. All that changed was how we chose to name the points/vectors on the plane i.e. our choice in basis.